# laravel - class not found for new service provider

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

i created a new folder ViewComposers and added a new file ViewComposer.php.
Path = App/Http/ViewCompers/ViewComper.php

Below is my code

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ViewComposer extends ServiceProvider{
     public function boot(){
            view()->composer('*', function (View $view) {
             $view->with('new_thread_comment_count', '50');
     });
}
```

and in my config\app.php i have added

```
'App\Providers\ViewComposer',
```

and i have also run composer dump-autoload.
But i still received **FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'App\Providers\ViewComposer' not found.**

Did i miss out anything?

Comment: what is the path of the ViewComposer class file ?

Comment: hi...App/Http/ViewCompers/ViewComper.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app folder is PSR-4 so the namespace of the class should reflect the class file path:

```
//set this namespace
namespace App/Http/ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposer extends ServiceProvider{
     public function boot(){
            view()->composer('*', function (View $view) {
             $view->with('new_thread_comment_count', '50');
     });
}
```

and, in config\app.php:

```
'App\Http\ViewComposers\ViewComposer',
```